# regex pattern to match specific number pattern , skip if there different pattern

Tags: java, regex

Requirement:

If pattern **57XXXXXXX** OR **57XXXXXXX-X** found in a sentence , then copy this matched pattern (**X**- denotes 7 integer number and **57** are constant values must be there), else ignore complete sentence.

I have written a regex pattern `57[0-9]{7}|-[0-9]{1}` to do match both the pattern.

If below pattern found(8 digits after 57 instead 7 , then still above regex still gets the matching pattern (actually expecting regex to not match)

for e.g.  5712345678-0 (after 57 , 8 digits in sentance)  --> regex matches and gives 571234567-0

Using java to compile above pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
\b57\d{7}(?:-\d)?\b
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In Java, that would be `Pattern.compile("\\b57\\d{7}(?:-\\d)?\\b")`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. i have tried your pattern for the numbers 5712345679-0 , got output as 571234567 . But my requirement is to ignore complete number format if it is not in  57XXXXXXX OR 57XXXXXXX-X found in a sentence .

Answer (score 1):

Not very different but allows letters and underscores around:

```
(?:(?<=[^0-9])|^)57[0-9]{7}(?:-[0-9])?(?:(?=[^0-9])|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookahead assertions in this case.

```
57\d{7}(?:-\d)?(?!\d)
```

Regular expression:

```
57              '57'
 \d{7}          digits (0-9) (7 times)
     (?:        group, but do not capture:
       -        '-'
       \d       digits (0-9)
     )?         end of grouping
      (?!       look ahead to see if there is not:
        \d      digits (0-9)
      )         end of look-ahead
```

Or:

```
(?:57\d{7})(?:-\d)?(?!\d)
```

Regular expression:

```
(?:             group, but do not capture:
  57            '57'
   \d{7}        digits (0-9) (7 times)
)               end of grouping
 (?:            group, but do not capture
   -            '-'
    \d          digits (0-9)
 )?             end of grouping
  (?!           look ahead to see if there is not:
    \d          digits (0-9)
  )             end of look-ahead
```